# How can i limit the effect of html code over a single div (or another element)

Tags: html, effect

```
<div>
<b> some test
</div>
another text
```

This would print the "another text" bold.
Is it some how possible to limit the effect of `<b>` only within the `<div>` element?
I've searched the web for some javascript solutions but couldn't find anything.

Please don't ask why I need this. Just lets assume it's out of curiosity.

Thanks

Comment: This is malformed HTML. What do you expect?

Answer (score 0):

Close the bold tag as shown below. This is basic HTML.

```
<div>
    <b>some text</b>
</div>
Another text
```

More on html here: http://www.w3schools.com/html/

Comment: I know that there is an error in code.
With this one I wanted to describe what kind of behavior I need. I need that the JS catches this error and does not allow to corrupt the rest of the code.
So please no more comments like "close the bold tag"

Answer (score 0):

A funny but working solution would be to inject closing tags in the element's innerHTML.

Let's think about :

JQuery

```
$('div').each(function(){
   $(this).append("</b></i></u></s></small></code>");
});
```

Pure JavaScript

```
var dv=document.getElementsByTagName('div');
for (var i=0;i<dv.length;i++) {
    dv[i].innerHTML += "</b></i></u></s></small></code>";
}
```

This is a really bad practice as you should always take care of closing every tags you may open, but this would close formatting tags if they are not closed yet.